# Can I generate database mysql from existing project developed in codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I generate database mysql from existing project developed in codeigniter framework?

Screenshot of the project structure is given below.

[image: screenshot of the project structure project]

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: I want to generate table in database from model in exists project codeigniter

Comment: this is as close as you are going to get in codeigniter: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are trying to generate migrations and seeders in Laravel, Similar thing is not possible in Codeigniter, 
Another better way to do this, create a PHP file for run the MySql, that you have wrote before

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use Codeigniter Migrations. That is if you are not a newbie.
You can read on it here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html

Else another option is to export your current database into an *.sql file and then import as your new database project using your SQL manager like PhpMyadmin.

Then go to your application/config/database.php file and change these settings

```
'hostname' => DB_HOSTNAME,//to your database host e.g localhost
'username' => DB_USERNAME,//your username for the host
'password' => DB_PASSWORD,// your password for the username
'database' => DB_NAME,// your database name
```